# Drawing Pattern in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to draw the following pattern in Python:

```
#      #
##    ##
###  ###
########
```

I can get the two right triangles separately but cannot figure out how to make them into one. Would anone be able to help me?

My code for the left triangle is:

```
rows = 4
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print('#', end='')    
    print()
```

My code for the right triangle is:

```
for i in range(0,rows):
    for j in range(0, rows-i):
        print(' ',end='')
    for k in range(0, i+1):
        print('#',end='')
    print()
```

I'm trying to combine them somehow but haven't been successful.

Comment: Please share the code you used to draw the triangles separately and perhaps explain a little what you tried to put them together, what you were expecting and what happened instead.

Comment: Try thinking the other way; assume that there is a single white triangle in the middle.

Comment: @Grismar I have updated my question to include my code for the two triangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it. '#' * x prints a increasing number of '#'s and space [(2*x):] slices the eight spaces in the string space.

```
space = '        '
for x in range (1, 5) :
    print ('#' * x + space [(2*x):] + '#' * x)
```

And here is a version without slicing.

```
y = 6
for x in range (1, 5) :
    print ('#' * x, end = '')
    if y > 0 : print (' ' * y, end = '')
    print ('#' * x)
    y = y - 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do it using just loops without the space and slicing?

Answer (score 1):

> 

This is a pattern program

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * *
* * * 
* *
*
```

the code for this program will be:

```
for i in range(0,7):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print("*",end=" ")
    print("\r")

for m in range(5,-1,-1):
    for n in range(0,m+1):
        print("*",end=" ")
    print("\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

try using string formatting with spacers like so:

```py
>>>print("{:<4}{:>4}".format('#','#'))
#      #

>>>print("{:x^7}".format('#'))
xxx#xxx

#f-strings
x = '#'
>>>print(f'{x:>5}')
    #
```

The formatting spacers add padding, to the left right, or both sides of a string

Answer (score 0):

Here assuming no.of lines *l =  4*

The min space starts with *s = 2*.

No.of hashes to print based on lines end = l * 2.

```
l = 4 
space = 2 
end = l * 2 
for i in range(1, l + 1):
    print('#'*i, end='')
    print(' '*(end - space), end='')
    print('#'*i)
    space = space + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
col=8
x=2
y=col-1

for i in range(1, col//2+1):
    for j in range(1, col+1):
        if(j>=x and j<=y):
            print(' ', end='')
        else:
            print('#', end='')
    x=x+1
    y=y-1
    print()
```

Comment: If you prefer your own answer over the other answers given, you can decide to accept it, but you should at least accept an answer to close the question if it has been resolved. If one of the other answers given was the primary inspiration for your solution, you could consider accepting that one.